# How to solve TypeError: string indices must be integers while removing specific rows using Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, dataframe, typeerror

Sample data.

[image]

I am trying to extract rows where 'compound' is negative.

I am using the below code:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv("Sample data.csv")
df1 = pd.DataFrame()

df1['Sentiment'] = df['Sentiment'].apply(lambda x: x if x['compound'] <= 0 else None)     # remove compound dictionary entry more than 1
df1.dropna(inplace=True)           #remove none lines
print(df1)
```

With this code, I am expecting it will remove positive (more than zero). However, I am getting the below error.

> TypeError: string indices must be integers

Any suggestions or solutions to solve this error?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `df['Sentiment']` is a `string` value, not a `JSON` object. You'll need to deserialize it to an object/dict first.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. Can you please elaborate with the example?

Comment: @PiyushGhasiya Please check my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider below `df`:

```
In [2424]: df = pd.DataFrame({'Date':['15/4/2020', '18/4/2020', '11/4/2020', '19/4/2020', '11/4/2020'], 'Text':['I am not feeling good.', 'We are going to pass this terrible time.', 'Sam is an awful actor.', 'Biden win is good for the US and the world.',
      ...:  '2020 is a very bad year'], 'Sentiment':["{'neg': 0.204, 'compound': -0.6249}", "{'neg': 0.204, 'compound': 0.34}", "{'neg': 0.204, 'compound': -0.4215}", "{'neg': 0.204, 'compound': 0.1027}", "{'neg': 0.204, 'compound': -0.2268}"]})

In [2425]: df
Out[2425]: 
        Date                                         Text                            Sentiment
0  15/4/2020                       I am not feeling good.  {'neg': 0.204, 'compound': -0.6249}
1  18/4/2020     We are going to pass this terrible time.     {'neg': 0.204, 'compound': 0.34}
2  11/4/2020                       Sam is an awful actor.  {'neg': 0.204, 'compound': -0.4215}
3  19/4/2020  Biden win is good for the US and the world.   {'neg': 0.204, 'compound': 0.1027}
4  11/4/2020                      2020 is a very bad year  {'neg': 0.204, 'compound': -0.2268}
```

I think your `Sentiment` column is a string. You need to convert it to a `dict` first.

```
In [2428]: import ast

In [2430]: df.Sentiment = df.Sentiment.apply(ast.literal_eval)

In [2437]: df = df[df.Sentiment.str.get('compound') < 0]

In [2438]: df
Out[2438]: 
        Date                     Text                            Sentiment
0  15/4/2020   I am not feeling good.  {'neg': 0.204, 'compound': -0.6249}
2  11/4/2020   Sam is an awful actor.  {'neg': 0.204, 'compound': -0.4215}
4  11/4/2020  2020 is a very bad year  {'neg': 0.204, 'compound': -0.2268}
```

Comment: Thank you so much. It worked. I was looking for a solution to this problem for a very long time. Thanks again.

Comment: Glad to help. Happy coding.